# redirecting www.www cname zone file

Tags: cname-record

I have configured a zone fine on dns and now if i type the domain it redirect to www.www.domain.com instead www.domain.com

Can anyoane help to sort it out and find what is wrong in the zone file?

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.dnsdomain.com. (
    2014052702   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      ns3.dnsdomain.com.
@                        IN NS      ns2.dnsdomain.com.
@                        IN NS      ns1.dnsdomain.com.

@                        IN A       192.168.1.10
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
mail                     IN A       192.168.1.10
www                      IN A       192.168.1.10
ftp                      IN CNAME   www
imap                     IN CNAME   www
loopback                 IN CNAME   localhost
pop                      IN CNAME   www
relay                    IN CNAME   www
smtp                     IN CNAME   www
@                        IN MX 10   mail
```

if i enter 192.168.1.10 in the web it redirect to www.192.168.1.10
if i enter www.domain.com it redirect to www.www.domain.com

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Can you run a couple of `NSLOOKUP`s on the things that are misbehaving? Also: have you definitely waited a refresh time etc? You shouldn't get redirected to 'www.192.168.1.10' in ... almost any circumstances, because that's nothing to do with your DNS.
Although, adding a DNS alias to localhost is pretty dirty.

Comment: "Redirecting" has nothing to do with DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Your zonefile looks fine.

The "redirect to www" sounds like a "browser-feature". Firefox does that, but normally only, if you don't enter the *www.*
The behaviour could also be caused by the webserver on 192.168.1.10.

As Sobrique suggested, try checking the name resolution with dig.
Using a webservice to determine that source of the problem, adds another layer of complexity.

Try something like

```
$ dig www.example.com
$ dig www.www.example.com
```

or

```
$ dig @ns1.dnsdomain.com www.example.com
```

to check the authoritative nameserver itself without a resolver in between.
You could also check your server/DNS settings with tools like http://www.intodns.com/

Also, be aware that if you use DNSmasq as resolver (used in a few home routers), it blocks resolutions to private IP addresses (RFC 1918) by default to prevent [DNS rebind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) attacks.

Do you host that nameservers in your local network? Or is the zonefile hosted at some provider? Could it be, that the provider filters the RFC 1918 addresses?